# jquery failed in ajax asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net

There some animations in a javascript file which makes divs to slide. so there is no error until I used the Update panels for my page . So now when I run my page with Update panels , the animations won't start! where is the problem?

Comment: there is no document.ready when UpdatePanel. use the pageLoad method.

Comment: give me an example please , like this : $(document).pageLoad(function(){})

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Microsoft Ajax Client Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397536.aspx)

```
// Attach a handler to the load event.
```

Sys.Application.add_load(applicationLoadHandler);

```
function applicationLoadHandler() {
    // Redirect to alternate page if not business hours.
    var d = new Date();
    if (!(8 < d.getHours() < 17)) {
        window.location = "AfterHours.aspx";
    }
}
```

[Sys.Application.Load Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383829.aspx)